# Receive Strings back from Server to Client using Websockets (Javascript and C++)

Tags: javascript, html, c++, boost, websocket

I'm new to the subject area so sorry If I've not explained things well.

I created a web API client that sends strings from my HTML (imbedded with JavaScript) back to a node.js server using Web Sockets.

I then swapped out the node.js server with a C++ application that still receives the string data perfectly.

My JS Client(within html script) :

```
function SendWSData(){
      const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:PORT");
     
      ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
        console.log("We are connected!");
       
        
      const stringvalue = `this is a test string`
       
        ws.send(stringvalue);
      });
     
      ws.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
      }
```

My C++ Server:

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>

using namespace std;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

string stringVal;

int main() {

auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address("IP");
        auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("PORT"));

        boost::asio::io_context ioc{1};

        tcp::acceptor acceptor{ioc, {address, port}};

tcp::socket socket{ioc};
acceptor.accept(socket);
std::cout<<"socket accepted"<<std::endl;

std::thread{[q = std::move(socket)]() mutable {

boost::beast::websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws {std::move(q)};

ws.accept();

while(1)
{
boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;

ws.read(buffer);

auto out = boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.cdata());


stringVal = out 

std::cout<<"stringVal = "<<stringVal<<std::endl;
}
}
```

This reads data coming into the buffer, and assigns it to a string variable on my C++ app, for me to use.

**My question is how would I go about sending back a string to the web page from the C++ app? (especially as my web page is the client and the C++ app is the server)**

I know that the server is meant to return a response which is standard, however does that change if I'm trying to implement a function based response? **I want to generate a button on the webpage and textbox, and when clicked I get string data from the C++ app.**

I've not found much online about sending data from server back to client, as I'm trying to get a request (which is the behaviour of a client). (Could I possibly generate another Web Socket and swap the roles of my web API and C++ app for this particular case; possibly multithreading it?)

Comment: [here is the information about boost::beast::websocket::stream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream.html). Do any of these functions sound like they send a message? The receive function is called "read", so any guesses for the send function?

Comment: Thank you very much; I think the write function could work; it would just be a case of sending it with respect to the buffer. e.g. ws.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));

Comment: I found that I can send strings from the c++ application using "ws.write(buffer.data());" however I'm not too sure about the receive function for javascript